# How to implement properties preprocessing before execution like it is done in Grunt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, replace, gruntjs, constants

Grunt has  syntax which is used to set and update configuration properties before task execution.

For example,

```
config {
  dist: {
     dir: "dir1"
  },
  clean: {
      dirs: [
          '<dist.dir>'
      ]
  }
}
```

becomes in memory to ...

```
config {
  dist: {
     dir: "dir1"
  },
  clean: {
      dirs: [
          "dir1"
      ]
  }
}
```

What npm module is responsible for this? Please, advice me how to implement it in a better way? Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure its `<dist.dir>` not `<%= dist.dir %>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template Strings within Grunt come from the [Lo-Dash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash) package.

References:

- [Grunt.template](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.template)
- [LoDash Template](https://lodash.com/docs/#template)