# How to create js constants object with "dependent/relative" values?

Tags: javascript, recursion, gruntjs, constants

I am working on js + php project and want to have constants class, where will store most common values for all code parts;

The problem is that these constants values are very relative to each other.
For example, lets imagine I have sources and tests directories. Both of them are stored like this:

```
src/
   main/
   test/
```

So, as I said I want to have constants object in javascript which have the following structure:

```
const CONSTANTS = {
    CODE: {
        CWD: 'src/',
        SOURCES: {
           DIRECTORY: '<%= CODE.CWD %>/src',
        },
        TESTS: {
           DIRECTORY: '<%= CODE.CWD %>/test',
        }
    }
}

exports.CONSTANTS = SomeLibraryOrSmthElse.process(CONSTANTS);
```

As you noticed, Grunt works in the same way.

How can I do this?

Comment: Answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37044974/how-to-implement-properties-preprocessing-before-execution-like-it-is-done-in-gr/37051768#37051768

Answer (score 0):

I would just extract the shared value as a variable and reuse it. The following code is using ES2015's template string literal assuming it's available because you have already put `const`.

```
const CWD = 'src/';
const CONSTANTS = {
    CODE: {
        CWD,
        SOURCES: {
           DIRECTORY: `${CWD}/src`,
        },
        TESTS: {
           DIRECTORY: `${CWD}/test`,
        }
    }
};
```